# Creating Folder For Each User

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've faced a problem when I was trying to set an htaccess code in my website

the code :

```
Options All -Indexes
Options +MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?q=$1
```

Now it's working when the url is : `www.example.com/john` it displays the user profile as `www.example.com/user.php?q=john`

but when the url became `www.example.com/blablabla/` it displays a destroyed webpage ! like this:

[image]

What to do please ?

Comment: can you check the browser's console and check the path it's attempting to load the css from?

Comment: Yeah, the page looks like it's loading but the path to the style sheet is broken.

Comment: Exactly, the problem occured when the url contains an unknown folder the the style cann't be loaded ! , Note : the style location is `style/style.css` , what can I do ?

Comment: The problem has been fixed by adding `/` at the first of the `<link>`'s css href, thanks all :)